# Should I use static classes in an ECS?

Tags: c++, static

Hey I am currently working on a small entity component system where there are classes like `EntityManager`, `ComponentManager` and `SystemManager` that are only instantiated once and heavily communicate with each other.

I created a class `world` which owns all the managers and acts as the center for all communication between the managers. Making all the Managers static would make a lot of things much easier, more understandable and I wouldn't even need the world class.

I know though that static classes (I know "static classes" don't exist but I mean classes with only static members) act as if they were global and global variables are Bad®.
 So I wonder what is recommended to do in this case

Thanks for your answers

Che

Edit:
The World class looks like this:

```cpp
class World
{
public:
    EntityManager* entityManager;
    ComponentManager<PositionComponent>* componentManager;
    MovementSystem* movementSystem;
    Entity e;

public:
    World(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    void update();
};
```

To communicate each Manager needs a pointer to the world to access the other managers. Like this `world->entityManager->getEntitys()`

Comment: Singletons and static variables are not necessarily bad itself, but often lead to an overall bad code structure, unclear dependencies, spaghetti code and not easies to understand lifetimes. The question is too broad to suggest a program structure for your use-case.

Comment: `Making all the Managers static would make a lot of things much easier, more understandable and I wouldn't even need the world class.` why? My first thought was, if the world is responsible for those managers, that it should own them and control their lifetime, so those mangers should be members (not static members) of the world instance.

Comment: You should use `std::unique_ptr` for the managers instead of raw pointers if the world is the only owner of the managers (which is most certainly the case, otherwise you would not think about using static).

Comment: Thanks I'll do that. When the Managers can communicate with each other directly I don't need a pointer to the world in every Manager.  And I don't have to make these long accessing calls

Comment: If you worrying about writing that over and over again then you could add a member function `EntityManager* entityManager() { return world->entityManager.get() }` and then you can write `entityManager()->getEntitys()`. Or create non owning raw pointer `EntityManager* entityManager;` in the other Managers and set it by the world, `componentManager->entityManager = entityManager.get()`. I personally would use `entityManager()->getEntitys()`

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<type>` would make these variables easier to manage. You won't have to `free` or `delete` them and you can be sure that these variables are only pointed to from one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I suggest that the project is a game or something close to it)*

I don't suggest you to make all members static. The main problem with it that you're loosing control on object's lifetime. You can't destroy and create new object at runtime easily because there is no object. For example, if you want to change a manager at runtime you'll have to implement cleanup code manually. In case of C++ objects C++ helps you with errors/warnings, default values and class members by value.

There are few popular ways to implement and use managers in gamedev:

- Use Singleton pattern. In this case class have one static method that returns link to non-static object.
- Pass dependencies that method requires during the method call manually.

**Singleton pattern**, I think, is the best way in terms of price-quality ratio for you. Despite on all criticism of this pattern it does its job well (most of game projects I saw used Singleton approach to implement manager classes).

There is an important thing I want to suggest you about this pattern. Don't use default implementation of Singleton pattern. Create methods for creating and destroying object instead of hiding it inside of getter. Here's simple example of glue code for a manager:

```
class Manager {
private:
    static Manager* ms_manager;
public:
    static void CreateManager() { ms_manager = new Manager(); }
    static void DestroyManager() { delete ms_manager; }
    static Manager* GetInstance() { return ms_manager; }
};
```

Usage is:

```
Manager::GetInstance()->SomeMethod();
```

**Passing dependencies** approach has its own advantages. It may sounds too difficult to pass everything in every Update method but it's not. You can create context class, set all dependencies there and pass it to every method that needs it. It's almost like your World class but it must be structure with minimum of code and no dependencies. Don't store there any game objects by value (only primitives, geometry vectors and stuff like this). It may be something like this:

```
struct Context {
    EntityManager* entityManager;
    ComponentManager<PositionComponent>* componentManager;
    MovementSystem* movementSystem;
    Entity* rootEntity;
};
```

Usage is:

```
GameObject::Update(Context& context) { context.entityManager->SomeMethod(); }
```

The point of this approach that you can tune context for some objects at runtime. For example, if you have LODs you can save in context current LOD level and change it at runtime for some objects depends on distance to the camera.

Comment: Thank you, interesting approach. Performance-wise, what is faster? Or is there not any difference?

Comment: I don't think there is any performance difference you should care about. Yes, there is an additional pointer dereference in case of context class but the difference will be on a CPU cache level. So, to notate it you have to have billions of Update calls per frame with absolutely performance-wise perfect body. Just make sure you're passing context object by reference.

Comment: One thing to note about a context is that they can have awkward interactions with `const` correctness, with severity increasing the more information is stored or referenced within.